# The application which is getting installed on samsung tab 10.1 is not getting installed on samsung tab 7.7

Tags: android

I have an application which fetches the device id. It is getting installed on phone and as well as on Samsung tablet 10.1. But when one of my friends is trying to install it on Samsung galaxy tab 7.7, it is not getting installed. What could be the reason behind that? The code which is fetching device id is as: `TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContex.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) telephonyManager.getDeviceId()`Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check what is the error?

Comment: have u allowed permission for not market application?if not than goto settings->application->unknown resources->and check the check box of it,than again try to install application.for more information see this  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-install-nonmarket-google-android-mobile-apps/

Comment: My friend checked that. Splash screen is coming and then it is getting crashed. Should we follow any other procedure to fetch the device id of samsung tb 7.7?

Comment: what logcat you are get when app crash on samsung tb 7.7 ?